# Why Temporary Topics Are Ideal Destinations For Reply Messages?

Tags: routes, tibco-ems

As per TIBCO docs:
Servers connected by routes exchange messages sent to temporary topics. As a result, temporary topics are ideal destinations for reply messages in request/reply interactions.

Can anyone explain me with example how is routed severs being able to exchange messages sent to temporary topics implies that Temporary Topics Are Ideal Destinations For Reply Messages?

Comment: Add some code and ask specifically

Comment: sinhayash, I want to know the meaning of this line "Servers connected by routes exchange messages sent to temporary topics. As a result, temporary topics are ideal destinations for reply messages in request/reply interactions."

Comment: anyone knows answer to this question?